# Simple DB and Amazon S3 performance tools

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-simpledb

Is there any benchmark tools that i can use to test the Amazon Simple DB performance and Amazon S3 performance?

help needed please.

Answer (score 0):

Its going to depend on you usage and whether you're running in EC2 or not. There are some benchmarks [somewhere](http://blog.rightscale.com/2007/10/28/network-performance-within-amazon-ec2-and-to-amazon-s3/) for S3 access from EC2, but your mileage will vary with object sizes, the SDK library you're using and where you're accessing from.

Roll your own tests and then you'll know that you're testing something close to your end goal...

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own code that approximates what you want to do.

Having said that: In my experience, S3 is about as fast as your connection. You may have to upload/download more than one item at a time to hit your local bandwidth limit, but you can get there.

Listing performance is also pretty good on S3, but the results are uncompressed XML, so they are little large. If you want to do 'something' to say a million files, you need to run several requests in parallel. This goes for SimpleDb too. The number of requests 'in flight' that works best is a mix of ping, bandwidth, AWS service response and other factors.

SimpleDB on the other hand I find to be pretty slow for many tasks. It totally depends on your needs, though. Selecting a record and getting back the attributes when you know the db item name is usually ping time limited, but searching with the %like% operator is usually quite slow (seconds is easy to hit).

Add to this that its all much faster if you are running on EC2 vs a local machine, and also add in the delay/bandwidth if your app is in say Singapore and you are trying to use the US Standard location to store everything. There is just too much to figure in.